# WPF prism: Dynamically load a type from an assembly and register it with the unity container

Tags: .net, wpf, dynamic, assemblies, prism

Here's what I am trying to do in the bootstrapper:

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
            Assembly someAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@".\SomeServiceImplementationLib.dll");

            Type someServiceImplementationType = someAssembly .GetType(@"SomeServiceImplementation");

            Container.RegisterType<ISomeServiceType, someServiceImplementationType >(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());


        base.ConfigureContainer();
    }
```

This doesnt compile saying "Type or namespace name expected" for someServiceImplementationType. But its indeed a type isn't it?

Basically I want to load a particular assembly only if certain conditions are met at startup and if its loaded I would like to register a service implementation from the loaded assembly with the unity container. Is there any way to do this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing compile-type generics and run-time typing.

Generics are a compile-time thing, unless you do a little bit of reflection magic to new up a new generic instance with the type... but that isn't necessary.

The Unity container has other extensions for RegisterType that are easy to use.

Instead, just call the non-generic form:

```
Container.RegisterType(typeof(ISomeServiceType), someServiceImplementationType, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```